# Lottie Animation: play animation even after AnimatedButton is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I am using an `AnimatedButton` from `Lottie` framework and it works fine but the only problem I have is that animation stops playing once the `AnimatedButton` is clicked, when I want the button to animate all the time, even after the click.

```
let middleButton = AnimatedButton()
    
 middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    
 middleButton.animation = Animation.named("eye")       
 middleButton.animationView.play()
 middleButton.animationView.loopMode = .autoReverse
 middleButton.animationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
 middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.middleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Have you tried animationView.loopMode = .loop

Comment: yes, sadly, no difference

Comment: Have you tried setting up the parameters before calling play() method coz when the play() method is called, then AnimationContext is created with all the then available values. I am giving an example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this just by initializing the lottie animation every time the button is pressed:

```
@objc func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
   
    // Animation logic
    middleButton.animation = Animation.named("eye")
    middleButton.animationView.loopMode = .autoReverse
    middleButton.animationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
    middleButton.animationView.play()
    
    didTapButton?()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below?

```
let middleButton = AnimatedButton()
    
 middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    
 middleButton.animation = Animation.named("eye")       
 middleButton.animationView.loopMode = .autoReverse
 middleButton.animationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
 middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.middleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
middleButton.animationView.play()
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! But for some reason, the animation still stops after tapping on the button even if play() is called after all the params are set :( It doesn't stop playing when I leave the app and come back or change tabs on the tabbar, but does when I actually press the button.